# Xpages: Page containing multiple of the same custom controls are not unique

Tags: javascript, xpages, custom-controls

I have created a nice custom control for an input text box for US currency. I want to be able to put this CC on a page multiple times, so I have made the field name a property. Everything seems to work right if there is one control on a page, but if there are more than that then the code in the CC is not working as intended. I am trying to do some validation and editing in CSJS inside the CC, and trying to get the unique computed ID when I do so. But it is not working - the first value overwrites the second value, and other weird things happen.

My code is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view
        xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
        xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
        xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
        createForm="false">
        <style> .errorRed{ border: 2px solid red; }</style>
        <xp:inputText
            id="curText1"
            value="#{viewScope.a}"
            styleClass="pull-right"
            style="width:200px;text-align:right"
            defaultValue="0.00">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber
                    type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute
                    name="input"
                    value="text-align: right">
                </xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onchange"
                submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[//Set some things

    var thisID  = '#{javascript:getClientId("curText1")}';
    var thisCmp = XSP.getElementById(thisID);
    var thisVal = XSP.getElementById(thisID).value;

    //Error if this is not a number
    if (isNaN(thisVal)) 
    {thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className + " errorRed";
    return}
    else
    {thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className.replace(" errorRed","")}

    //Must remove $ and any commas
    y = thisVal.replace(',','');
    z = y.replace('$','');

    //Must fix to 2 decimal places
    if ((typeof z) === 'string'){
        z = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2)}
    else {
        z = z.toFixed(2)
    }   

    //Now put it back in the field
    thisID.value = parseFloat(z);
    XSP.partialRefreshPost(thisID);]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:view>


I am adding my modified code:

Custom Control:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    createForm="false">
    <style>.errorRed{ border: 2px solid red; }</style>  
    <xp:scriptBlock
        id="scriptBlock1"
        type="text/javascript">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[formatNumber = function(thisID) {
var thisCmp = XSP.getElementById(thisID);
var thisVal = XSP.getElementById(thisID).value;

//Must remove currency symbol and any commas
y = thisVal.replace(',','');
z = y.replace('$','');

//Error if this is not a number
if (isNaN(z)) 
{thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className + " errorRed";
return}
else
{thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className.replace(" errorRed","")}

//Must fix to 2 decimal places
if ((typeof z) === 'string')
{z = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2)}
else    
{z = z.toFixed(2)}  

//Now put it back in the field
thisID.value = parseFloat(z);
XSP.partialRefreshPost(thisID,{execId:thisID, immediate: true});

}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:inputText
        id="curText1"
        styleClass="pull-right"
        style="width:200px;text-align:right"
        defaultValue="0.00"
        value="#{compositeData.price}">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber
                type="currency"
                currencySymbol="$">
            </xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="input"
                value="text-align: right">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onblur"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var thisID = '#{javascript:getClientId("curText1")}';
formatNumber(thisID);]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>

    <xp:inputText>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:{"${"+compositeData.bla+"}"}}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

Here is the code for the Xpage, with 2 custom controls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xe:objectData
                var="doc">
                <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:var doc = new com.scoular.model.Project();

var unid = sessionScope.get("key");

if (unid != null) {
    doc.loadByUnid(unid);
} else {
    doc.create();
}

sessionScope.put("key",null);

return doc;}]]></xe:this.createObject>
            </xe:objectData>
        </xp:this.data>
        </xp:panel>

    <xp:panel id="numbers">
        <xc:cc_CommonInputCurrency2
            field="total1"
            bla="#{doc.prjAmtColumn11}">
        </xc:cc_CommonInputCurrency2>
    </xp:panel>

        <xp:panel id="panel1">
        <xc:cc_CommonInputCurrency2
            field="total2"
            bla="#{doc.prjAmtColumn12}">
        </xc:cc_CommonInputCurrency2>
    </xp:panel>

</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your value property is bound to `viewscope.a`. In the rendering phase that scope has one and one value only, so all your fields are bound back to the same. 
The better way is to use a parameter in your custom control to provide the value. So you would have something like `<cc:moneyControl bla="document1.price">` 
Then you use a field you give the CSS attribute hidden and bind it to `#{"${"+compositeData.bla+"}"}` and let your dojo update that field. Saves you a server trip and having an extra field outside the CC. 
How it works: the $ gets evaluated once and first and forms any valid data source, not only documents.

Hope that helps

Comment: You can also pass both the document and the field's name as parameters to your CC, e.g. in dataSource and fieldName. Then you can use the Expression Language code binding expression: compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]

Comment: Which then limits you documents only and excludes beans or scoped variables - or other data sources

Comment: Actually I am using a bean. Stwissel, I have tried to code what you have above in your answer, but I am not yet successful. I am going to put my code under the original question. I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Only `bla="doc.prjAmtColumn12` - if you add #{ there the resolution happens on the page, but you need it in the control. More explanations here: https://prezi.com/m/gubendoqbl1t/custom-controls-enlightenment/

Comment: `#{"${"+compositeData.bla+"}"}` results in a run time error. Change it to `#{${javascript:compositeData.bla}}`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues, first the code:

```
       <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="input"
                value="text-align: right">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
```

should be using `<xp:this.dojoAttributes>` :

```
       <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute
                name="input"
                value="text-align: right">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
```

Second, your `isNaN` check should come after your strip out the dollar sign and comma, like this:

```
//Must remove $ and any commas
y = thisVal.replace(',','');
z = y.replace('$','');

//Error if this is not a number
if (isNaN(z)) 
{
  thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className + " errorRed";
  return
}
else
{
  thisCmp.className = thisCmp.className.replace(" errorRed","");
}

//Must fix to 2 decimal places
if ((typeof z) === 'string'){
    z = parseFloat(z).toFixed(2)}
else {
    z = z.toFixed(2)
}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference in the dojo attributes?

Comment: `xp` vs. `xe`. Using `xe` gives me an error in Designer.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I changed it now. I still am not able to keep multiple custom controls separate, even after this. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Maybe doing a Project->Clean then Build to ensure it's not an issue with the build. If you do a `console.log(thisID)` you should be getting different IDs per each instance of the custom control on your XPage.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the field bound to a scoped field, one sure way to have a dynamic "private" variable inside a custom control is to name it using the clientId of from one of its components.

Example:
Create a panel that wraps the content of the custom control. Set an id on the panel to wrapper.

To set the scoped variable:

```
viewScope.put( getClientId( 'wrapper' ), 'someValue' )
```

To get the scoped variable:

```
viewScope.get( getClientId( 'wrapper' ) )
```

If you need access to the scoped variable outside the custom control, you could specify the client id of a component in the XPage as field name (compositeData) for the custom control using the same logic.